# How to create user in Linux without attributes in default group?

Tags: users

I know, how create with attributes

```
adduser -n username
```

GROUP, we find in `/etc/default/useradd`. But in `login.defs`, we can add something.

Comment: [`adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/adduser) has command line options that can override  `login.defs`. Which particular field are you having trouble with?

Comment: I do not know how to add a user without attributes, but that it was in the default group

eg.
adduser user1
adduser user2

Add to group 101 for example, without specifying the parameter -n.



Said that it is possible to add something in login.defs, somehow specify a group of 101 to no attributes added to her people, and not in each group for itself.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is that `adduser user1` creates `user1` and puts them in the group `101` by default, you should change these lines in [`/etc/adduser.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/adduser.conf.5.html):

```
# The USERGROUPS variable can be either "yes" or "no".  If "yes" each
# created user will be given their own group to use as a default.  If
# "no", each created user will be placed in the group whose gid is
# USERS_GID (see below).
USERGROUPS=yes

# If USERGROUPS is "no", then USERS_GID should be the GID of the group
# `users' (or the equivalent group) on your system.
USERS_GID=100
```

So in your case you would have:

```
USERGROUPS=no
USERS_GID=101
```